# How to develop a function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $z := \frac{x-a}{y}$ where $a$ is a non-zero constant. Then is there any function $f$ such that 
$$f(z) = f\left(\frac{x-a}{y}\right) = \frac{x}{y}?$$

Comment: @Cbjork No they don't.

Comment: yea I realized that after I press submit

Comment: How? If $f$ is constant, say, $f(t) = d$ then $f(z)=d \neq \frac{x}{y}$.

Comment: I misread the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ be a fixed nonzero constant. Then there is no function $f$ satisfying
for all $x,y$ ($y \neq 0$) the following $$f \left( \frac{x-a}{y} \right)= \frac{x}{y}$$

Proof: suppose $f$ exists, and consider $x=y=1$. Then
$$1= \frac 11 = f \left( \frac{1-a}{1} \right)= f \left( \frac{2-2a}{2} \right) = f \left( \frac{(2-a)-a}{2} \right) = \frac{2-a}{2}$$

from this $a=0$ follows, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

$$\forall y \neq 0, f \left(\frac{0-a}{y} \right)= f\left( \frac{-a}{y} \right) = 0$$

Hence if it exists, it must maps every non-zero entries to zero.

That is $\forall k \neq 0$, let $y=\frac{-a}{k}$, we have $f(k)=0$

However, we also want $$f \left(\frac{2a-a}{2} \right) = a \neq 0$$

which is a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, constant function does not work.